# How to create relationships in a RESTful API

Tags: api, rest

I have 2 tables, User table and User_token table,  they are one to one/none relatonship, not sure how to create this RESTful API.

i prefer to setup

```
# to get user attributes 
GET /users/123

# to get user's token 
GET /users/123/token
```

or should i create

```
# to get user attributes and token by JOIN the table
GET /users/123
```

the argument we have here, if we are doing the first setup, which i like it, it takes thousands of API requests compare to second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is depend you requirement.

for example if you need **User Attributes** and **Token** every time than

```
# to get user attributes and token by JOIN the table
GET /users/123
```

is better.

other wise another approach is good to get required data when needed.

Answer (score 0):

REST has nothing to do with your database structure.

Your resources can contain properties or sub-resources. Every resource has at least one resource identifier (URL).

So in your case the `GET /users/123` is a valid solution.